# python multiproccess - send db connection

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to have 2 processes: one for collecting data and store it to sqlite database and one for using the data.

I'm trying to pass to the collecting process a handle to sqlite, but getting an error. Below is my simplified code

```
import sqlite3
import multiprocessing
import time


def do(db_handler):
    print("start inserting data")
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(1)
        db_handler.execute("insert into temp_table (f1, f2) Values (?,?)", (i, i*2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = sqlite3.connect("temp_db.db", check_same_thread=False)
    dBhandler = connection.cursor()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do, args=(dBhandler,))
    p.start()

    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(1)
        result = dBhandler.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks")
        rows = result.fetchall()

        print("i =", i)
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
        print("============")
```

I'm receiving an error: `TypeError: Can't pickle sqlite3.cursor objects`

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You can't pass handles across processes.  The second process will load a brand new Python interpreter and will execute your entire file again.  You should put all of your global code in an `if __file__ == '__main__' block.  What are you gaining with the multiprocessing?

Comment: The collection of the data is pretty heavy process which includes various streams (including live video), from which I have to filter only some packets. P.S. code was updated, but same error

Comment: And you see what the error is telling you, right?  Multiprocessing uses pickle to transport global objects to the new processes.  You can't pickle an Sqlite cursor.  However, it costs practically nothing to create a new cursor, so just move that line into `do`.